# In Python edit Non Global Names

Tags: python, function, graphics, global

In Python Version: 2.7.5,
I have Zelle's Graphics installed and I have no idea what to do because I am trying to edit a non global name in a function with a different function.
Here is an example of my code.

```
from graphics import *
import time
keyPad=GraphWin("Key Pad",300,400)
def Game():
    Buttons()
    testFor_keyPad_press()
def Buttons():
    button1=Rectangle(Point(1,1),Point(100,100))
    button1.setFill('gold')
    button.draw(keyPad)
def testFor_keyPad_press():
    userInput=keyPad.getMouse()
    userInputX=str(userInput.getX())
    userInputY=str(userInput.getY())
    if(userInputX<101 and userInputY<100):
        button1.setFill('grey')
        keyPad.update()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        button1.setFill('gold')
        keyPad.update()
Game()
```

I thought that should work, but it gives me an error saying that global name 'button1' is not defined... so is there a way I can edit button1 inside of the user defined function "Buttons()" ? Or is that not possible? Please let me know if there is a way to do this or not... all help is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def Buttons():
    global button1
    button1=Rectangle(Point(1,1),Point(100,100))
    button1.setFill('gold')
    button.draw(keyPad)
```

would make it accessible outside the function ... but really you should probably encapsulate your logic in classes

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand what you mean by "encapsulating my logic"